# I need a good way to discard image views in my iOS game

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I have about 10 draggable objects in my game that need to be removed entirely from the game at certain points, no use of these objects is required until a new game is started...

currently i say self.imageView = nil

However, the more images i discard this way, the slower the game becomes. I believe it is because the images are not completely gone and they are all being put at (0, 0) even though they are out of the view.

How else can i get rid of these image views in order to increase my performance?

Here is how I add the images to my view:

```
@interface GameView : UIView
{
   UIImage *ball;
}

@property UIImageView *redBall;

-(id)initWithBallImage:(UIImageView *)ball;

@implementation GameView

-(id)initWithBallImage:(UIImageView *)ball
{
  self = [super init]
  if (self)
     {
      _redBall = ball;
      return self;
   }
  return nil; 
}

-(void)spawnBallWithColor:(BallColor)ballColor intoArray:(NSMutableArray *)array atPoint:(CGPoint)point 
{
  switch (ballColor) {
    case kRedBall:
      ball = [UIImage imageNamed:@"redBall.png"];
      self.redBall = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:ball];
      self.redBall.center = point;
      [array addObject:self.redBall];
      [self addSubview:self.redBall];

      break;
}

//I use the above method in an initWithLevel: method...
```

Then to remove the object from the view...

```
[self.redBall removeFromSuperview];
```

Comment: Are you removing the image views from their super view and how do you create the images displayed by the views?

Comment: I think it's time to post some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[self.redBall removeFromSuperview];
```

You also need

```
self.redBall = nil;
```

And you need to remove it from that array you added it to.

Additionally

```
self.redBall = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:ball];
```

Is leaking memory if you aren't using automatic reference counting.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. I am using ARC and i added in the nil statements but the more objects i removeFromSuperview and nil the slower my program runs. Any other ideas?

Comment: Are you removing it from the array? `[array addObject:self.redBall];` needs some corresponding `removeObject` call.

Comment: This is where I run into problems. As I said they are draggable objects so in my touchesMoved: method I run through all of the objects in my ball array. If I remove an object from the array I get an error saying something along the lines of "you can't modify an array that is in use"

Comment: You can't modify an array while using fast enumeration. This is illegal: `for (NSObject *obj in array) if (test(obj)) [array removeObject:obj]` Instead do `for (int i = 0; i < [array count]; i++) if (test([array objectAtIndex:i])) [array removeObjectAtIndex:i--]`